# Edited scope in dev tools before making an $http request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope

When making an $http.post() call, what would be a good way to make sure the user does not go to developer tools and change the variables being sent?

For example:

```
$http.post('/api/ratings', { name: $scope.item.name, rating: $scope.item.rating, ... })
```

If the user sets a breakpoint right before the call, they're able to edit the scope variables being sent to something else. I now have a rating for an item that doesn't exist in the database...

I could check to see if the item exists before saving it on the server side, but would prefer not to slow things down.

Comment: You start making use of cookies or sessions to validate this call? One way or another injecting or manipulating the data send to the server is a big issue and you should reconsider a back end check as well.

Comment: I do, just wanted to see if there was another approach on validating data other than making 2 separate calls on the server (one for validating and another for saving). Thanks.